# Asynchronous method 'anonymous' should not return void

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, prism, anonymous-function

Can someone help me resolve this problem I tried everything.
I usually know how to resolve that problem but not with anonymous method.
DelegateCommand has 2 constructors.

1) public DelegateCommand (Action executeMethod)

2) public DelegateCommand (Action executeMethod, Func canExecute).

I wanna know is it possible some how to remove that warning. Async and await are needed otherwise my method: enterButtonClicked(); would be called synchronously.

```
 ...
    public DelegateCommand EnterButton { get; set; }

    public StartPageViewModel()
    {
        Title = "title_black.png";
        PasswordPlaceholder = "Lozinka";

        EnterButton = new DelegateCommand( async () => { await enterButtonClicked();}); // <----- I am getting that warning here
    }

    public async Task enterButtonClicked()
    {

    }
...
```

Comment: You need to show us the signature of DelegateCommand's constuctor. Most likely, you are creating a "async void" function because DelegateCommand does not contain a constuctor that takes in a `Func<Task>`. Just do `new DelegateCommand(enterButtonClicked)` and it should be more obvious what the problem is.

Comment: It has two constructors 1) public DelegateCommand (Action executeMethod) and 2) public DelegateCommand (Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecute). I wanna know is it possible some how to remove that warning. async and await are needed otherwise my method: enterButtonClicked(); would be call synchronously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

async await is only compatible with `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>` if you don't have that then you have what is considered a "Async void" which you should not do.

Your two options are to not await the task

```
...
public DelegateCommand EnterButton { get; set; }

public StartPageViewModel()
{
    Title = "title_black.png";
    PasswordPlaceholder = "Lozinka";

    EnterButton = new DelegateCommand( () => { var temp = enterButtonClicked();}); 
}

public async Task enterButtonClicked()
{

}
...
```

which means any exceptions raised by enterButtonClicked will go unnoticed

or use a better delegate command that supports async functions. Personally I like the AsyncCommand from the [Nito.Mvvm.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.Mvvm.Async) NuGet package written by [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary).

```
...
public AsyncCommand EnterButton { get; set; }

public StartPageViewModel()
{
    Title = "title_black.png";
    PasswordPlaceholder = "Lozinka";

    EnterButton = new DelegateCommand(enterButtonClicked); //you can just use a delegate, no method needed.
}

public async Task enterButtonClicked()
{

}
...
```

The `AsyncCommand` delegate sets `CanExecute` to false while the task is running so a person can't repeatedly click unless the action has completed.

Comment: Thank you very much for a very nice explanation.