# Xamarin Essentials browser call giving Asynchronous method 'Anonymous' should not return void

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I updated Visual Studio and now I am getting a lot of messages like this:

```
public ICommand OpenWebPageCmd => new Command<string>(async (url) =>
{
   await Browser.OpenAsync(new Uri(url), BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
});
```

> Asynchronous method 'Anonymous' should not return void

I saw some other answers that were not specific to this extension. Is there any way I can resolve this when using the Browser option to open a new page?

Comment: Not sure but I think it's the lambda expression you have which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354014/7462031) explains that

> async await is only compatible with `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>` if you don't have that then you have what is considered an "Async void" which you should not do.

Since `Browser.OpenAsync` return a `Task` and not a `Func<Task>` you have two options

1. Not await the task:

   ```
    public ICommand OpenWebPageCmd => new Command<string>((url) =>
    {
     Browser.OpenAsync(new Uri(url), BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
    });
   ```
2. Use a better delegate command that supports async functions. Like the AsyncCommand from the [Nito.Mvvm.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.Mvvm.Async) NuGet package written by [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary).

For more information read the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46353690/7462031)